# A few issues with FireBase and location - Optionals, location and user saving

Tags: swift, firebase, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am making an ap that tracks users who sign up, this will be used for Hunting mostly.

The main problem i am having is when I save a location it makes a user in firebase with the name Optional"User" when I just want it to be "username", I tried unwrapping the optional show in this code for currUsername but if I do that it saves right, but does not allow location saving right away and says it finds nil when unwrapping the optional currUsername!

This is my code I am having issues with:

```
  @IBAction func getCoords(sender: AnyObject)
{
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

}

@IBAction func logoutButton(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let myRootRef = Firebase(url: "https://hunttracker.firebaseio.com/");
    myRootRef.unauth();
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.logout, sender: nil)
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{

    let latValue = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
    let lonValue = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude

    LatLabel.text = String(latValue)
    LongLabel.text = String(lonValue)
    let myRootRef = Firebase(url: "https://hunttracker.firebaseio.com/users/\(**nameSingleton.currUsername!)"**);

    let usersRoot = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("Location")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: usersRoot.childByAppendingPath("LocationData"))

   geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: lonValue, longitude: latValue), forKey: "Values"){ (error) in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Saved location")
            self.pintomap()
        }
    }

}
```

One more question onto this is, how would I go about saving a table view offline so that the data I pull from firebase stays there, and also updates when a user changes location? I will put the table code below if anyone has an idea but the first question is my main problem.

```
  @IBAction func addMember(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Party Member",
        message: "Add Party Member",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add",
        style: .Default)
        { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
             nameSingleton.addedmember = alert.textFields![0].text
            //query if party member exists 

            self.myRootRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:
                {

                    snapshot in


                    //print(snapshot.key)
                    var memberslist = [String]()
                    memberslist.append(snapshot.key)
                    for(var i = 0; i < memberslist.count; i++)
                    {
                      if(memberslist[i] == nameSingleton.addedmember)
                      {
                        nameSingleton.partymembers.append(nameSingleton.addedmember!)
                        }
                    }
                                })
            self.getdata()
            nameSingleton.currUsername = alert.textFields![0].text

        }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textName) -> Void in
        textName.placeholder = "Enter your Username"
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you to whoever can help

Comment: To avoid crashing due to `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value` you can use conditional binding to safely unwrap your optional. --> `if let name = nameSingleton.currUsername { //do something}`. The reason it is crashing is because the value of `nameSingleton.currUsername` == `nil` at the time of that line being executed. You need to make sure that it has a value other than `nil`. Wherever you are setting the value of that var, use some print statements to see what is going on

Comment: I will give that a shot! thank you

Comment: No problem. Also, you should either delete your second question, or make it a question of its own, as it really is an entirely separate question

Comment: That first comment sounds like an answer Mike. :-)

Comment: so its forgetting the user that is logged in when the app closes so I need a way to save that user even when the app closes so it knows theyre logged in still. Is there a good way to accomplish this ?